# Why does tempfile and os.chdir() throw RecursionError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
import os, tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    os.chdir(tempdir)
```

Why does this throw a RecursionError? How is this bit of code recursive in the first place? How would I go about changing the working directory to that of a temporary one?

Comment: The traceback should show you where the code loops.

Comment: Not able to reproduce the problem with provided code

Comment: Can you add the full traceback error that you get, along with any surrounding code from this snippet? Using just this snippet I get no errors.

Comment: @KJTHoward Here's the traceback: https://hastebin.com/abamarijit.sql
And there is no surrounding code, it's just this "with" statement.

Comment: There's your real error message: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`. You have to leave the folder before it gets destroyed. This might be unique to less tollerant operating systems.

Comment: @KlausD. You're right. Changing working directory back to original rids the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error is this: `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

The working directory needs to be changed before `tempdir` is deleted.